# How to set permissions on directory?

Tags: command-line, osx-lion, file-permissions

I am searching for a way to set permissions on folder and the contents.

The rule is as such that the only the superuser can delete contents of the folder. Users can add, view, modify, but **not** delete the files in the directory.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Are you concerned about users deleting files but not, for example, opening them up and deleting all of the contents?

Answer (score 2):

Use the icacls command:

`icacls "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\folder" /grant "Domain Users":f /t /q`

This command will grant read/write permissions to all domain users in `folder` and all files and subfolders in it.

Explanation:

```
/grant
:r  Read Access
user:permission
:f  Full access
/t  Traverse all subfolders to match files/directories.
/q  Quiet - supress success messages.
```

Comment: MAC OS X 10 Lion

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This will work with windows only. I am currently using Mac OS X Lion.